# Apache proxy cookies works only with the first app

Tags: apache, tomcat, cookies, proxy, reverse-proxy

stuck on configuring apache as proxy for applications running on tomcat on different pc. Everything seems working on the first application - WebApp1. But on the left ProxyPassReverseCookiePath is not working. ProxyPassReverseCookiePath works only on the first application. When accesing other applications a jsessionid is added to the url. 
What I missed and how to fix on WebApp2 and WebApp3? Thanks

httpd-vhosts.con:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /WebApp1/ ajp://192.168.1.98:8009/WebApp1/
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApp1/ ajp://192.168.1.98:8009/WebApp1/
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApp1/ http://192.168.1.98:8080/WebApp1/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /WebApp1 /WebApp1/

    ProxyPass /WebApp2/ ajp://192.168.1.98:8009/WebApp2/
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApp2/ ajp://192.168.1.98:8009/WebApp2/
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApp2/ http://192.168.1.98:8080/WebApp2/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /WebApp2 /WebApp2/

    ProxyPass /WebApp3/ ajp://192.168.1.98:8009/WebApp3/
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApp3/ ajp://192.168.1.98:8009/WebApp3/
    ProxyPassReverse /WebApp3/ http://192.168.1.98:8080/WebApp3/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /WebApp3 /WebApp3/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by changing to cookie path location dir:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /WebApp1/ http://192.168.1.98:8080/WebApp1/
```

Comment: I had some trouble with WordPress behind a reverse proxy. Most things worked fine after the initial configurations, but some still didn't. Took me a long time to even find out this had sth to do with cookies. This solution was exactly what I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the advantages of **ajp** is that it sends the original URL to the web application. So any transformations by `ProxyPassReverse` and `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` are not necessary, so you can just leave those directives out.

Unrelated to that, `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` simply replaces the `path` parameter in the cookies that come from the web application. As in your case, the path that the web application is accessed under is the same as the path under which it is made available by Apache, it is not necessary to replace anything in the cookie path.

I could imagine that the reason why your original code doesn’t work is because it replaces `/WebApp1` by `/WebApp1/`, so you might end up with `/WebApp1//` in the cookie path, which might confuse browsers. (I am neither sure whether Apache does the transformation in this case nor whether it confuses the browsers.) I could imagine that the solution that you posted works because Apache ignored the directive because it contains an invalid path. (I am also not sure whether that’s how Apache behaves in this case.)

Comment: You say ajp sends original URL. Doesn't it depend on how `ProxyPreserveHost` is set?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and following configuration fixed my problem.

step-1: Added `ProxyPreserveHost On` property on vhost.

step-2: configured ProxyPassReverseCookiePath for all the application like below

```
   ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /   /WebApp1

   ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /   /WebApp2

   ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /   /WebApp3
```

Hope this will help!