# WordPress behind reverse proxy: Session-cookies not set in Safari & IE

Tags: wordpress, apache, safari, session-cookies, reverse-proxy

I have a WordPress blog running behind a reverse proxy (Apache).

**httpd.vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName blog.domain.com:80
    ServerAlias www.blog.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.101.11/blog/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.101.11/blog/
</VirtualHost>
```

The blog works fine, I can log in as admin, ***but*** when try to save settings or delete a plugin (and a wp_redirect occurs) I am redirected to the login page, because wordpress obviously doesn't find/accept the session cookie, and the action doesn't get completed.

Therefore, I have added this line:

```
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / http://192.168.101.11/blog/
```

(see [Apache proxy cookies works only with the first app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913975))

This seemed to solve the problem. ***However***, I have noticed now, that with this setting, the login does not work at all, but ***only*** in Safari and IE (works just fine in Opera, Firefox, Chrome). I just get redirected to the login page again.

**Some additional information:**

- The session cookies and `wordpress_test_cookie` for the admin section are not created at all in Safari, only the ones like `"__uc*"` etc. (for the blog itself). Without the `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`-entry, they *are* created.
- I activated cookies for third-party-sites (in both browsers), this didn't solve the problem.
- I've configured WP-cookies this way:

**wp-config.php**

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.blog.domain.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin' );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solved it:**

I made a slight mistake in the cookie path configuration. It has to be:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath http://192.168.101.11/blog http://blog.domain.com
```

Answer (score 4):

`ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` performs a transformation of the `path` attribute of cookies. This attribute contains only a path, so passing a full URL to the directive will not work. I’m not sure why it didn’t work for you without the `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` directive, but I assume that Wordpress did not respect the `COOKIEPATH` that you set.

The correct configuration would be:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /blog/ /
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 192.168.101.11 .blog.domain.com
```

This will transform both the `path` and the `domain` of your cookies, and thus makes the settings you made in `wp-config.php` obsolete.